# Perl Warning on Iterating a Hash

Tags: perl, hash, foreach, warnings

The following code has baffled me for a while by giving this warning message: `Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./mycode.pl line 666.` where line 666: `print "@{n0->{$x}{$y}}\n";`. Note that, `n` is a hash of hash of array of strings that looks like as follows:

```
n  = (
 x0 => {
   y0 => [ "foo00", "bar00" ]
   y1 => [ "foo01", "bar01" ]
   ...
 }
 x1 => {
   y0 => [ "foo10", "bar10" ]
   y1 => [ "foo11", "bar11" ]
   ...
 }
...
)
```

Here is the code:

```
my $rn =\%n;
for my $x (keys %$rn){
    print "$x\n";
    for my $y (keys %{$rn->{$x}}){
        print "@{$rn->{$x}{$y}}\n";
    }
}
```

I don't understand why Perl should complain about `uninitialized values`. Essentially, I expected that the elements must have had values otherwise they wouldn't even exist and thus wouldn't appear in iterations. Moreover, the output is matching what I expected.

What is the crux that I am I missing here? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: dunno if it's the only problem, but `@{rn...` should be `@{$rn...`

Comment: @ysth thanks, that was a typo. I fixed the question description.

Comment: You should not type in code in your question. You should cut and paste code that you have run, and you are sure works the way you say it does. We have no use for approximate code when troubleshooting, we need specifics. Preferably, you should create an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @TLP I did exactly what you said. Except for the input `n`. Check how the first answer was made based on the question.

Comment: @AliAbbasinasab, no, you didn't copyed. Because your 666 (devil) line is: `print "@{n0->{$x}{$y}}\n";` so, instead of demo-code `$rn` in the real code youre using `n0`. So, it isn;t a "copy". ;)

Comment: @AliAbbasinasab As jm666 says, no you didn't copy/paste, because you had a typo in your code. Your main problem is not this part of your code, however, but the code which populates your hash. The proper procedure would be to bugproof your code there, to make sure no undefined values are entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, there appears nothing wrong with your code.  Therefore your data is at issue.

I would recommend using a module like [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) (my preference) or [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) to inspect your data.  Then you can determine more easily not only which key has the bad data, but which value.

If you want to be fancy, you can even create a special [`$SIG{__WARN__}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) handler to only output the additional information if an error is found.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %n = (
    x0 => {
        y0 => [ "foo00", "bar00" ],
        y1 => [ "foo01", "bar01" ],
    },
    x1 => {
        y0 => [ "foo10", undef ],
        y1 => [ "foo11", "bar11" ],
    },
);

my $rn = \%n;
for my $x ( keys %$rn ) {
    print "$x\n";
    for my $y ( keys %{ $rn->{$x} } ) {
        # Catch Warning and output additional info
        local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
            warn @_;   # Output regular warning info
            use Data::Dump;
            dd $x, $y, $rn->{$x}{$y};
        };

        print "@{$rn->{$x}{$y}}\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
x1
foo11 bar11
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at b.pl line 24.
("x1", "y0", ["foo10", undef])
foo10 
x0
foo01 bar01
foo00 bar00
```

Comment: Dawmn, that's what I was looking for since 1740.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works; see what's different in your code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %n = (
 x0 => {
   y0 => [ "foo00", "bar00" ],
   y1 => [ "foo01", "bar01" ]
 },
 x1 => {
   y0 => [ "foo10", "bar10" ],
   y1 => [ "foo11", "bar11" ]
 }
);

my $rn =\%n;
for my $x (keys %$rn){
    print "$x\n";
    for my $y (keys %{$rn->{$x}}){
        print "@{$rn->{$x}{$y}}\n";
    }
}
```

Perhaps your data is not exactly what you think it is?
Add a `use Data::Dumper; print Data::Dumper->new([$rn])->Useqq(1)->Terse(1)->Dump;` and see if anything there gives you a clue.

You can track which values in particular are triggering the warning by putting this just before the print:

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print "warning given when x is $x and y is $y: ", @_ };
```

That said, unless one of the array elements is undefined, I can't get your warning to happen at all unless I set `$"` to undef (though you are on an ancient version of perl and I am not, so that perhaps makes a difference.)  If in fact you are changing `$"` (which is normally a space character), you should avoid interpolating an array in a string and instead explicitly do:

```
print join(" ", @{$rn->{$x}{$y}}), "\n";
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can see for which specific iteration the warning has been issued?

Comment: Presumably you would see which key issues the warning, since you are printing the keys. But that is really not necessary. If you print the data structure with `Data::Dumper` you will see with your own eyes where the `undef` value is.